# Как вытащить "Нужный текст"

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

`<a class="filter__link">Нужный текст<span class="filter__count" >Ненужный текст</span></a>`

Как вытащить "Нужный текст" из такой структуры `html`?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, выделить весь текст и удалить из него ненужное:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '<a class="filter__link">Нужный текст<span class="filter__count" >Ненужный текст</span></a>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
unnecessary = soup.find('span', class_='filter__count').text
full_text = soup.find('a', class_='filter__link').text

necessary = full_text.replace(unnecessary, '')
```

В `necessary` в итоге:

```
>>>necessary
'Нужный текст'
```